# How to correctly pass a string argument to XPATH in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, xpath, sql-injection

How to pass a string argument to `EXTRACTVALUE`?

For instance:

```sql
EXTRACTVALUE(fooColumn, '/foo/bar[@baz = "arg"]/@value')
```

How to replace `"arg"` with a real argument `:arg`?

Naive solution:

```sql
EXTRACTVALUE(fooColumn, '/foo/bar[@baz = "' || :arg || '"]/@value')
```

How to prevent possible "XPath" injection here?
Is there a XPath escape function?

Comment: `EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated.

Comment: @MT0 I know that `EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated.

Comment: So are you asking about how to do this specifically with `extractvalue`, or just for any way to do it?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am wondering how it is possible using `EXCTRACTVALUE`. I know that I can use PASSING clause in `XMLQUERY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated and you should be using `XMLQUERY` or `XMLTABLE` instead.

You can try using the `DBMS_ASSERT` package:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION enquote_name (
  name IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  -- Wrap it in a function call to use the PL/SQL FALSE literal.
  RETURN DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(name, FALSE);
END;
/
```

Then:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         ('/foo/bar[@baz='||ENQUOTE_NAME(:arg)||']/@value')
         PASSING fooColumn
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS value
FROM   table_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( foocolumn, '/foo/bar[@baz='||ENQUOTE_NAME(:arg)||']/@value')
         AS value
FROM   table_name
```

Which for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( foocolumn ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE(
'<foo><bar baz="abc" value="123" /><bar baz="def" value="456" /></foo>'
)
FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs, when `:arg` is `def`:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 456 |

If you try to use `:arg` as `'abc"][@value="123'` then the query returns zero rows (or raises an exception for `EXTRACTVALUE`); but if you try passing the same value without wrapping it in the call to `ENQUOTE_NAME` (and include the double quotes that `ENQUOTE_NAME` would add) then it would perform the XPATH injection that you were trying to avoid.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20d421540c5ead7d236ef4fe076799ae)*

Comment: Why you use `ENQUOTE_NAME` for `XMLQUERY`? `PASSING` clause of XMLQUERY accept arguments.

Comment: @TN. It is a way of solving your problem and if you choose to use, the deprecated, `EXTRACTVALUE` then you can use exactly the same method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just your answer is now a bit misleading (XMLQUERY with ENQUOTE_NAME). But thank you for the ENQUOTE_NAME.